# How can I get first row of each group after using groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have pandas dataframe which has columns `X, Y, Z`. I need to get `maximum` of `Z` for each value of `X` and also I need to keep corresponding values of column `Y`.

I tried following code:

```
s_pts = inv_trans_df.groupby(['X', 'Y'])['Z'].max()
```

When I run this code the the output that I get is

[image]

Instead of this I want this to be like:

0.62933 | 0.68162 | 0.27078

0.62938 | 0.68136 | 0.26827

Comment: Why do you ignore the 2nd row, i.e. `0.62933 | 0.68162 | 0.27078` ?

Comment: Sorry about the mistake. I just need row which has maximum value of Z in each group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an index of the rows that have the maximum Z value for each X by:

```
idx = inv_trans_df.groupby(['X'])['Z'].transform(max) == inv_trans_df['Z']
```

Then that index will give you every row that has a max Z for a given X and you can select Y or whatever you want to do from here.

```
inv_trans_df[idx]
```

Note that this will retain any duplicates - if a value of X has a max Z that occurs more then once, all of the matching maximum values will appear in the result. How you deal with this will depend on what your actual goal is.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by value and then drop duplicates by the first of your indexing series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('ABAB'*3),
                   'col2': list('XYYX'*3),
                   'col3': list(range(12))})

res = df.sort_values('col3', ascending=False)\
        .drop_duplicates('col1')

print(res)

   col1 col2  col3
11    B    X    11
10    A    Y    10
```